# Are Encryption, Key Exchanges and Digital Signature the application of asymmetric encryption

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, key-exchange

Reading the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Applications) on asymmetric cryptography, will I be wrong to conclude that there are 3 main broad category of application for asymmetric cryptography? Mainly:

- encryption
- digital signatures
- key exchanges

Or are there other category of applications for asymmetric cryptography that do not fall under these 3 things?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a bit more complicated than that. There are many different applications and some applications can be implemented with either symmetric or asymmetric primitives.

See [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) for example, on pages 3-4 of Chapter 1, for an overview.

All of the following can be implemented using asymmetric cryptograpic primitives:

privacy (confidentiality)

data integrity

entity authentication or identification

authentication (data origin authentication)

signature

validation

access control

certification

timestamping

witnessing

receipt

confirmation

anonymity

non-repudiation

The crucial thing in asymmetric cryptography is that anyone (with no access to a shared secret) can perform the relevant function securely and reliably.